# Create terminal to command

Tags: folder, command-line

I have to create several projects with a folder structure, in those folders will be some files.

Every time I have to create a project, I have to create a folder, copy folders and files from another one and paste on the new folder.

I want to make this as easy as possible and thought about using a terminal command to do so, like:

projects create "project_name"

Ubuntu will then create the folder and files on the new project folder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

I use a PHP framework, CodeIgniter, I need to replicate its structure to other folders, I need to make it as dynamic as possible.

EDIT:

What I need is something like this?

codeigniter create "project_name"

When I press Enter, it will copy all files and folders from a defined location and paste it on a new folder, also on a defined location with the Project_name.
The location must be defined because it needs to be on a Apache htdocs folder

Comment: It seems rather simple, but the information are less than needed to give a real answer.

Comment: what else do you need?

Comment: For example, the new project folder structure can be simply copied from a skeleton, with some modification? And what modication you need? Please, put new information directly in the question.

Comment: ok, project_folder will be folder where new project will be created, project name will be name for that project (ie. /"project_folder"/"project_name"/ ?), or it will echo name to some file or what ? please specify. It looks like simple bash script, will type it if noone else will, but specify this first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put together a simple script to do this.

The following will do what you want assuming the original codeignitor source is in /usr/local/src/codeignitor

The code will need to be saved into a file called codeignitor in your PATH. 
An ideal place would be to create a folder called bin in your home directory and save it in there. The permissions will need to be set to allow execute permissions.

To create a new folder called new_project, you will run the command as

```
codeignitor create new_project
```

The script is as basic as it can be so will need to be extended if this is the sort of solution you need, here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

src='/usr/local/src/codeignitor/'

cmd=$1
dest=$2

case $cmd in
    create )
        cp -av $src $dest
        ;;
    * )
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```